# JQuery click event firing when DOM object appended

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

**Desired functionality:** I have a JQuery function that appends new elements to the page. These new elements CAN be clicked to call the creator function again, but should NOT call click function as soon as created.

**Problem:** When function is fired, the new elements are appended and the on("click") function gets fired recursively and infinitely.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" value="test"/>
<div id="divContainer">
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
    createDiv();
});

function createDiv(){
    $("<div id='innerDiv'>Div element</div>").appendTo("#divContainer").on("click", createDiv());
}
```

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/uWXbA/

**Obs:** This is not the real code, it's an extract of the problem itself.

Comment: Looks like you got it :)

Comment: Yup, it was hard to see for the first time, but it is a good spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part:

```
.on("click", createDiv())
```

Is calling the `createDiv()` function. You want to pass a reference to the function, like this:

```
.on("click", createDiv)
```

Or, as you have it above, wrapping in an anonymous function also works:

```
.click(function() {
    createDiv();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QayWP/

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. That was a silly mistake, and your solution solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JQuery

```
function createDiv(){
    $("#divContainer").append("<div class='innerDiv'>Div element</div>");
    $(".innerDiv:last").click(function(){
        createDiv();
    });
}
```

You should add the div with the attribute class instead of id beacuse it can be repeated.